# How not to load images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code:

```
$("img").not("div.counters img, div.l-column.l-column_1 img").each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("data-src", src);
    $(this).attr("src", "./frontend/web/img/loading.gif");
});
$("img").not("div.counters img, div.l-column.l-column_1 img").unveil(200).load(function() {
    console.log('image loaded');
});
```

**I needed to was a sequence:**

1) The user visited the site and saw before downloading "loading.gif."

2) Once the image is downloaded by the user, it will appear in place of "loading.gif."

**What I have now:**

1) The user visited the site and saw the original picture.

2) Once the load script he saw "loading.gif."

3) Then immediately changed to the original image.

***How not to display at the beginning of the original image?***

Comment: This is interesting, and it can be used in relation to my code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, but if you want to hide your img, why not use display:none; and display:block; when the right img as at the src?

Comment: Sorry, but you probably did not understand me. I need to exercise lazy loading images. I just can not change tags img of code to add the data-src and change the src, I can influence them only through JQuery.

Comment: Still not clear what your issue is and why you can't use css to help you

Comment: I see you want to lazy load your images.. still, why not just hide your img at the beginning, you could do that in jquery or css.. with jquery it would be $("yourimgselector").hide()

Comment: skip the first step. Start the image off with loading.gif first and data-src with the old src, then with js preload the img in data-src and update src when done.

Comment: Kevin B Interesting idea, could I give you an example with my code. I slightly understand what to do.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem has not been solved ...

Answer (score 0):

Keep the image "loading.gif" in CSS, make it background of container where you want the image to displayed initially.

```
  .loading-image{
                 background-image:url('loading.gif');
                }
```

Once the image has been downloaded, place the image onto the container and SIMPLY remove the classname.

```
   $(".img-container").removeClass('loading-image');
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.. Please correct me if I'm wrong.